# OAuth Code Flow with PKCE for Azure AD and Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, pkce

All the samples and documentation provided by Microsoft only mention PCKE for SPA applications in a browser. Is that flow supported for Xamarin native apps when MSAL is used ?

Answer (score 1):

The [OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) can be used in apps that are installed on a device to gain access to protected resources, such as web APIs. Using the Microsoft identity platform implementation of OAuth 2.0, you can add sign in and API access to your mobile and desktop apps.In order to use Auth 2.0 authorization code grant for mobile you need to use a native redirect uri (and ask them to register one) or register a URI handler so that the redirect to your app.

Yes you can use **OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow with PKCE**(Proof Key for Code Exchange) to obtain the Auth code which supports Mobile Devices and the scenario is supported for Xamarin. Please go through the supporting document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-mobile-overview).

Please let us know if you still need any help.